# Android WallpaperManager.setResource crashes activity

Tags: android, crash

I'm trying to set a wallpaper from a resource and every time I do that the activity crashes. Here's the code:

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());  
try {
    myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.wallpaper_1);
} catch(IOException e) {    
    Toast.makeText(wallpaper.this, "Wallpaper error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The Toast never shows up and the log just reads

```
Process com.test.app (pid 1583) has died.
```

immediately followed by

```
WIN DEATH: Window{b47fab10 com.test.app/com.test.app.MainActivity paused=false}
```

I tried both with jpg and png images but none seem to work. Any idea what I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget the permission: "android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"
in your AndroidManifest.xml file. :)

Comment: Ok I thought that was the problem...issue of security

Comment: Yeah, it turns out it was commented out for some reason. *facepalm*. thank you

Answer (score 0):

try to use bitmap

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());  

try {

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.wallpaper_1);

            Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 600, 300,
                    false);

            myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmapResized);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help sunil, it turns out I commented out the permissions line, no idea why. Going to go shoot myself in the leg next, just to keep the momentum going :)